# 301 redirect not working joomla

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla

I am trying to rewrite the URLs in .htaccess in joomla 
here is my .htaccess

```
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
Redirect 301 /properties.html?view=property&id=4:land-for-sale-kotturpuram-chennai /land-for-sale-kotturpuram-chennai.html
```

So at the bottom you will see that I am using `redirect 301`

It is not working.I end up seeing 404 page. In my joomla admin panel, All the SEO settings

Search engine friendly URLs , Use URL rewriting, Adds Suffix to URL , Unicode Aliases are set to yes.

Or is there any other better way to remove the `properties.html?view=property&id=4:` and so on from the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` doesn't match `QUERY_STRING` you will need to use mod_rewrite rule only.

Try this rule on **before all of your rules**:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=property&id=4:land-for-sale-kotturpuram-chennai$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^properties\.html$ /land-for-sale-kotturpuram-chennai.html? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I have more than 40 links( and counting) like that. I cannot be writing 2 lines for each URL. 
`properties.html?view=property&id=5:abc-acb-acb-acv` and many. I would like to change each URL to SEO friendly URL.

Comment: I tried your two lines for this particular URL. It did not work.

Comment: Well fact remains that you CANNOT match query string using `Redirect` directive and any flavor of `mod_rewrite` rule will require 2 lines.

Comment: well rule definitely works (I have tested it), you just need to make sure this is your first rule in `.htaccess` and your input URL is: `/properties.html/?view=roperty&id=4:land-for-sale-kotturpuram-chennai`

Comment: I tried your concept. No luck. I am reminding you that I am just trying to rewrite the URL and there is no such `/land-for-sale-kotturpuram-chennai.html` page actually exists.

Comment: If `/land-for-sale-kotturpuram-chennai.html` doesn't exist then what do you think your `Redirect` rule was doing?

Comment: I am using the same concept in one of my website. It all works fine.

Comment: My concern is why is that not working here? Am I missing something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41162/discussion-between-venky-and-anubhava)